# Vb6 Error code Equivalent in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling, vb6

Is there is any way to convert a vb.net error code number to a vb6 error code number.

Eg: divide by zero error code in vb6 is 11

How to get the same equivalent in vb.net?

Comment: I think you may use `On Error GoTo` to hundle the Error, not `Try/Catch`

Comment: But any way to convert to try catch instead of on error. Also any way to map error code or any links

Comment: You need to create a dictionary to cross reference errors.  vb.net doesn't use error numbers so you have to convert string to number.  vb6 is an entirely different compile since the combined the C# V6, and VB V6 libraries in to a single Net Library.  In doing the combining, a lot of things changed.

Comment: just to be in the same context, are you using two codes, one on VB6 and the other on on .Net, and you want to get the same error number on both code ? Am I right ?

Comment: yes @raed , i need to convert the error code

Comment: You would need to generate a list of the VB6 codes you are interested in then map them to the equivalent VB.Net *Exception types

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same error code numbers by using the legacy error handling `On Error Goto x` in VB.NET. This allows you to inspect the `Err.Number` just as you would in VB6.

There is no direct equivalent when using a `Try Catch Finally` error handling block as exceptions do not have a number associated with them and there are not directly equivalent anyway. Here is a list for reference: http://www.mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/dotnetexceptions.html

Have a look at this page which discusses the differences between VB6 and VB.NET error handling techniques: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973849.aspx

I would have to ask why you need to do this in the first place as I suspect there is a better alternative to whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: We can user the error code using Err object but is there any mapping of vb6 error codes with vb.net error codes on sql exceptions

Comment: No. Please see above.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the same code Error ?
You can use somthing like this on .Net :

```
Try
    System.IO.File.Delete("c:\test.txt")
Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    'Statements
Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
    'Statements
Catch ex As System.Exception
    'Statements
End Try
```

On VB6 :

```
On Error Goto ProcError

  ' code that raises an error

ProcExit:
  Exit Sub

ProcError:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case X
      ' handle X
    Case Y
      ' handle Y
    Case Z
      ' handle Z
    Case Else
      ' default
      MsgBox Err.Description
      Resume ProcExit
  End Select
```

After that, all you need is to customise the output for each case.